# Web-Page page not loading when using headless Selenium Chrome driver on Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, headless

I'm doing a bit of scraping from some local site which posts events in my town. They show both Past and Future events. I'm interested in the Future Events only, so when running the scrape I use the following bit of code to scroll down to Past Events (this means that the entire Future Events table has been loaded):

```
my_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Past Events')]")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", my_element)
```

It works flawlessly, giving me all the information I need. But when I attempt to go headless it throws me the following error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), 'Past Events')]"}
```

I use this bit of code to go headless:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

So when going headless it cannot longer find Past Events text. If I delete the bit of code which finds Past Events (at this point I'll settle for anything in order to go headless), the scraper will not return anything anymore, so basically it won't be loading any events at all when headless.

Any ideas on how I can force the page to load fully in headless mode?

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [**TOS 3.2**](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use _Facebook API_ instead.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'll stay away from FB since their API does not return Events anymore. I'm also trying to scrape a local event page (which does allow scraping) and I get the same issues.